# Emacs defaulting to emacs.d as a file

Tags: ubuntu, emacs

No matter where I am or how I open emacs, I get this message:

```
File exists: /home/{user}/.emacs.d/
```

I then have to `C-x C-f` to get to the file I was trying to edit. What is going on here, and how do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: What does `ls -la ~/.emacs.d` say?

Comment: `drwx------  2 root root 4096 Sep 23 10:54 auto-save-list`

Comment: That can't be the full output.  `ls -la` on a directory should include the `.` and `..` entries.

Comment: @cjm That is correct. I did not include the `.` or `..` directories.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get this error if `~/.emacs.d` exists but is not a directory readable by your user.  From the partial output of `ls -la ~/.emacs.d` you gave, it appears that you somehow managed to get a `.emacs.d` directory in your user's home directory that's owned by root and has no permission for your user.

You could try (as root)

```
chown -R user:yourgroup /home/user/.emacs.d
```

where `user` is your username and `yourgroup` is your user's primary group.

Comment: If that is the meaning of this error message then I would suggest that someone use `M-x report-emacs-bug` to ask for a more meaningful error message. As it stands, the message is not helpful and is in fact misleading.  (Just one opinion.)

Comment: This changing the owner fixed it. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a file called ~/.emacs.d and emacs where to attempt to look in a directory called ~/.emacs.d/ for a file names init.el, it would encounter an error such as this. If you have a file called ~/.emacs.d perhaps you could move it to init.el and put it in a directory names ~/.emacs.d

If not then there could be a line in your legacy emacs config file ~/.emacs that is attempting to create this directory.

Comment: I have no file `~/.emacs.d`, `init.el`, or `/.~emacs`.

Answer (score 0):

The cause may be running emacs as root ("sudo emacs ...") before running it as the logged-in user. I did this while setting up my system, and ran into the same problem. Emacs of course creates the .emacs.d directory if it does not exist, and if emacs is running as root, the directory will be created with root as owner.

The same applies to the .emacs file -- you might want to check the ownership of that, too.

Changing the owenership from root to the user fixes the problem, as has been noted.